# C Programming Modify Quicksort

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, gcc

Homework question out of the textbook "Modify the qsort.c program of section 9.6 so that low, high and middle are pointers to array elements rather than integers. The split function will need to return a pointer not an integer."

qsort.c Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10

void quicksort(int a[], int low, int high);

int split(int a[], int low, int high);

int main(void)

{

int a[N], i;

printf("Enter %d numbers to be sorted: :", N);

for (i=0; i<N; i++)

    scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    quicksort(a, 0, N - 1);

    printf("In sorted order: ");
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void quicksort(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int middle;

    if (low >= high) return;
    middle = split(a, low, high);
    printf("Low");
    printf("%d", low);
    quicksort(a, low, middle - 1);
    quicksort(a, middle + 1, high);
}

int split(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int part_element = a[low];

    for (;;) {
        while (low < high && part_element <= a[high])
            high--;
        if (low >= high) break;
        a[low++] = a[high];

        while (low < high && a[low] <= part_element)
            low++;
        if (low >= high) break;
        a[high--] = a[low];

    }

    a[high] = part_element;
    return high;
}
```

My Attempt at the Solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

void quicksort(int a[], int *low, int *high);
int split(int a[], int *low, int *high);

int main(void)
{
int a[N], i;
int zero, nminus;
printf("Enter %d numbers to be sorted: :", N);
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    zero=0;
    nminus=N-1;
    quicksort(a, &zero, &nminus);

    printf("In sorted order: ");
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void quicksort(int a[], int *low, int *high)
{
    int *middle;
    int splitt;
    if (low >= high) return;
    splitt = split(a, low, high);
    middle = &splitt;

    quicksort(a, low, middle - 1);
    quicksort(a, middle + 1, high);
}

int split(int a[], int *low, int *high)
{
    int low1, high1;
    low1= *low;
    high1= *high;
    int part_element = a[low1];

    for (;;) {
        while (low1 < high1 && part_element <= a[high1])
            high1--;
        if (low1 >= high1) break;
        a[low1++] = a[high1];

        while (low1 < high1 && a[low1] <= part_element)
            low1++;
        if (low1 >= high1) break;
        a[high1--] = a[low1];

    }

    a[high1] = part_element;
    return high1;
}
```

I am new to c-programming and am unsure how to make this program work correctly. This attempt debugs successfully however it just spits out the input without sorting it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

void quicksort(int a[], int *low, int *high);
int* split(int a[], int *low, int *high);

int main(void)
{
    int a[N], i;
    printf("Enter %d numbers to be sorted: :", N);
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    quicksort(a, &a[0], &a[N-1]);

    printf("In sorted order: ");
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void quicksort(int a[], int *low, int *high)
{
    int *middle;
    if (low >= high) return;
    middle = split(a, low, high);

    quicksort(a, low, middle - 1);
    quicksort(a, middle + 1, high);
}

int*  split(int a[], int *low, int *high)
{
    int part_element = *low;

    for (;;) {
        while (low < high && part_element <= *high)
            high--;
        if (low >= high) break;
        *low++ = *high;

        while (low < high && *low <= part_element)
            low++;
        if (low >= high) break;
        *high-- = *low;

    }

    *high = part_element;
    return high;
}
```

**Correspondence table**

```
 when sizeof(int) is 4
 address | array a | index of array
 a(top)  |   a[0]  |        0
 a + 4   |   a[1]  |        1
 a + 8   |   a[2]  |        2
 ...

 &a[1] is (a + 4) : address of a[1]
 *(a+4) is a[1] : (a+4) is a + 1*sizeof(int), *(a+1) in c
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes much more sense

Answer (score 1):

If you take the top, and copy and paste it, the following changes are really all that have to be made:

Every time you compare high, low, or middle, just keep the -- or ++ and then dereference it such.  For example:

```
 a[high1--] = a[low1];
```

goes to

```
 *(high--) = *low.
```

Then, all you have to do is pass the pointers high, low, and middle around.

Answer (score 1):

It says:

> The split function will need to return a pointer not an integer.
>
> int split(int a[], int *low, int *high);

Return a pointer not an integer.

int *split(int a[], int *low, int *high);